# Solving a quadratic matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

This might be a well-known problem but I am having trouble to find this. For square matrices $X, A, B,$ how to obtain the general solution for $X$, for the quadratic matrix equation $X A X^{T} = B$ ? What are the existence and uniqueness conditions for such solution?

Comment: What sort of numbers make up the entries of the matrices?  The problem is a bit harder if they are restricted to integers than if they are arbitrary complex numbers.

Comment: I was looking for the case when matrices have real entries. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This relationship is called congruence, and for symmetric (or hermitian) matrices $A, B$ such an $X$ exists if and only if the matrices have the same inertia (the same number of positive, negative, zero eigenvalues). Fro general matrices congruence is much less well known, but it *is* quite well understood, see:

https://gauss.uc3m.es/fteran/papers/2010-1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am wondering if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive semi-definite, then can we write $X$ explicitly in terms of $A$ and $B$? I am trying to get a result similar to Theorem 1 here: https://kb.osu.edu/dspace/handle/1811/22234?mode=full

Comment: I very much doubt it. For $B=I,$ you are asking for a system of eigenvectors for $A,$ which is a question which has received a lot of attention over the last couple of centuries. If there were a closed form, that would be quite amazing.

Comment: @IgorRivin Actually, for $B=I$, you are asking for a factorization $A= YY^T$ (with $Y=X^{-1}$), which is an easier problem than eigenvectors, and has a closed formula via the Cholesky factorization.

Answer (score 2):

I read the reference of Igor, but I  have nothing shot about our equation !

There is a case that seems less difficult. If $A,B$ are symmetric complex, then the problem is essentially equivalent to solve $2$ equations of the form $ZZ^T=D$, that is, the case $A=I$ or $B=I$.

equation 1:  $YY^T=A$ , equation 2: $ZZ^T=B$ , equation 3: $XY=Z$. If $A,B$ are invertible, then $Y,Z$ exist and $X=ZY^{-1}$.In these conditions, can we find, at least in theory, all solutions ?

For Halder. The equation $XAX=B$ is easy to solve (at least when $A$ is invertible) because it can be rewritten $(XA)^2=BA$.

EDIT: Let $A,B\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$. According to a result by Turnbull, Aitken (cited in the Igor's reference) our equation admits a solution iff $A,B$ are congruent iff there are invertible $P,Q$ s.t. $PAQ=B,PA^TQ=B^T$. Then, for generic $A,B$, the equation $XAX^T=B$ has no solutions. Thus, the "good" equation is $XAX^T=CAC^T$. Using my computer, I randomly choose real matrices $A,C$ ; I find that the algebraic set of complex solutions has dimension $1$ when $n=2$, $1$ when $n=3$, $2$ when $n=4$, $2$ when $n=5$.