# Closed form solution for $XAX^{T}=B$

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, matrix-equations

Let $d \times d$ matrices $A, B$ be positive definite. Is there a closed form solution for the following quadratic equation in $X$?

$$X A X^{T} = B$$

Thank you.

Comment: Just for completeness: this is usually called a Ricatti equation, sometimes also a Lyapunov equation. This might help to lookup references if needed.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/78106

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving a quadratic matrix equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78106/solving-a-quadratic-matrix-equation)

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I think Federico's answer is very neat, at least for the type of problem I specified.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$B^{-1/2}XAX^TB^{-1/2}=I$, so $B^{-1/2}XA^{1/2}=Q$ must be orthogonal. On the other hand, for any orthogonal $Q$, it is simple to verify that $X = B^{1/2}QA^{-1/2}$ solves the equation, so this is a complete parametrization of the solutions.

Here $A^{1/2}$ is the symmetric square root of $A$ (if you prefer you can work with the Cholesky factor and obtain similar results).

Comment: @federico-poloni thank you, this was very helpful, could you elaborate on how the Cholesky factor approch would looke like?

Comment: @user_na If $B=MM^T$ and $A=LL^T$, then following the same steps one gets that $M^{-1}XL=Q$ satisfies $QQ^T=I$.

Comment: And with that, $X=MQL^{-1}$, right?

Comment: The question asks about positive definite matrices, not symmetric matrices. However, if $A^{1/2}$ is a symmetric square root, $A^T = (A^{1/2}A^{1/2})^T=A$, so $A$ is also symmetric. The given solution only works if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. Unfortunately Federico Poloni's answer doesn't answer the question in general as I thought. If the question intended to ask about symmetric matrices, maybe it should be edited.

Comment: @wikiwert AFAIK the standard definition of "positive definite" includes "symmetric"; if you mean "Hurwitz anti-stable" (all eigenvalues in the right half-plane) please specify it.

Comment: In any case, the non-symmetric case is much more involved as far as I know; a good starting point is: Canonical forms for congruence of matrices: a tribute to H. W. Turnbull and A. C. Aitken. F. De Terán. SeMA Journal, 73 (2016) 7-16.