# Matrix equation and spherical harmonics

Tags: linear-algebra, harmonic-functions, spherical-geometry, orthogonal-matrices

I have a set of functions expanded in a finite number of spherical harmonics (up to degree $L$),
$$
\eta_k^n(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l=0}^L \sum_{m=-l}^l d_{kl}^{nm} Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
Similar to the spherical harmonics, my $\eta_k^n$ functions satisfy the condition
$$
\eta_k^{-n} = (-1)^n (\eta_k^n)^{*}
$$
Written in vector form, we have
$$
\boldsymbol{\eta} = D \mathbf{Y}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are vectors of length $(L+1)^2$ and $D$ is a square matrix of size $(L+1)^2 \times (L+1)^2$ with elements $d_{kl}^{nm}$. My functions $\eta_k^n$ do not satisfy an orthogonality condition, and so I would like to define a new set of functions
$$
u_k^n = \sum_{lm} b_{kl}^{nm} \eta_l^m
$$
or
$$
\mathbf{u} = B \boldsymbol{\eta}
$$
such that the $u_k^n$ are orthonormal with respect to the usual inner product over the unit sphere,
$$
<f,g> = \int d\Omega f g^{*}
$$
The coupling matrix for the $u_k^n$ is given by
\begin{align}
C_{\mathbf{u}} &= \int d\Omega \mathbf{u} \mathbf{u}^{\dagger} \\
&= \int d\Omega B \boldsymbol{\eta} \boldsymbol{\eta}^{\dagger} B^{\dagger} \\
&= B C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}} B^{\dagger}
\end{align}
where $C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}} = D D^{\dagger}$ is the coupling matrix of the $\eta_k^n$ functions. In order to make the $u_k^n$ functions orthonormal, I require that
$$
C_{\mathbf{u}} = B C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}} B^{\dagger} = I
$$
So my problem becomes: **given $C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}} = D D^{\dagger}$, find a matrix $B$ which satisfies $B C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}} B^{\dagger} = I$.**

This problem is not unique, as there are multiple (possibly infinite?) matrices $B$ which will satisfy that equation for a given matrix $C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}}$. However, I would like to impose the additional constraint that the orthonormal functions $u_k^n$ also satisfy the symmetry condition,
$$
u_k^{-n} = (-1)^n (u_k^n)^{*}
$$
This leads to the following condition on the elements of $B$:
$$
b_{kl}^{-n,m} = (-1)^{n+m} (b_{kl}^{n,-m})^{*}
$$
So at last I arrive at my question:

**Given a positive-definite matrix $C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}}$, find a matrix $B$ which satisfies $B C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}} B^{\dagger} = I$ and also satisfies the constraint**
$$
b_{kl}^{-n,m} = (-1)^{n+m} (b_{kl}^{n,-m})^{*}
$$
If anyone has any ideas on how to approach a problem like this, I would greatly appreciate it!

EDIT: If we remove the constraint, then one possible way to solve the (unconstrained) problem is to perform a Cholesky decomposition of the matrix $C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}} = L L^{\dagger}$. Then we have
$$
B C_{\boldsymbol{\eta}} B^{\dagger} = (B L) (B L)^{\dagger} = I
$$
and so $B L \in O((L+1)^2)$ where $O(n)$ denotes the orthogonal group of $n \times n$ matrices. One possible choice is simply $B = L^{-1}$.

This simple solution however does not satisfy my desired constraint, so a more sophisticated approach is needed.

Comment: Note that all solutions can be written in the form described in your edit; see https://mathoverflow.net/q/366111/1898 .